# TypeError: message.guild.channels.find(...).then is not a function

Tags: javascript, discord.js

This is the error I am getting from my code below: `TypeError: message.guild.channels.find(...).then is not a function`

```js
        message.guild.channels.find('name', `${message.author.username}-oda`).then(c => {
            channel.overwritePermissions(message.member, {
                CONNECT: true,
                VIEW_CHANNEL: true
            });
            message.channel.send('All Ok.')
        })
```

Comment: Hello,  can you provide a bit more context and include more code?   .then is a method of a promise so it's likely to do with the '.find' function not returning a promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you commented on this answer saying you're using discord.js v11 and not v12 I am editing my answer according to tipakA's comment below.

> `find` does not return a Promise, so you cannot use `then` on it.

Your solution would be:

```js
const channel = message.guild.channels.find('name', `${message.author.username}-oda`);
channel.overwritePermissions(message.member, {
                CONNECT: true,
                VIEW_CHANNEL: true
            });
message.channel.send('All Ok.');
```

Comment: I did as you said. It is giving an error like this right now:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined

Comment: @DES If you are not on v12 of discord.js, that answer is not for you. If you are on v11, `find` does not return a Promise, so you cannot use `then` on it.

Comment: The version of discord.js is v11 so Is it possible to solve it.

Comment: He just told you the solution, I edited my answer according to tipakA's comment to make it clearer