# TypeError: message.guild.channels.find is not a function discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeerror, discord.js

The following code is producing the error in the title:

```js
message.guild.channels.create("ticket-" + data.ticketCounter, 
{
  type: 'text',
  parent: '702634860363382784',
  permissionOverwrites: [
    {
      id: message.guild.id,
      deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL']
    },
    {
      id: message.author.id,
      allow: ['SEND_MESSAGES', 'VIEW_CHANNEL', 'ADD_REACTIONS', 'EMBED_LINKS', 'ATTACH_FILES', 'READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY', 'USE_EXTERNAL_EMOJIS']
    },
    {
      id: "702701257290154044",
      allow: ['SEND_MESSAGES', 'VIEW_CHANNEL', 'ADD_REACTIONS', 'EMBED_LINKS', 'ATTACH_FILES', 'READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY', 'USE_EXTERNAL_EMOJIS']
    }
  ]
})

const ticketEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setColor(config.embedColor)
  .setTitle('New ticket from ' + message.author.tag)
  .setDescription(messageContent.join(" "))

const ticketChannel = message.guild.channels.find('name', `ticket-${data.ticketChannel}`);
ticketChannel.send(ticketEmbed)
```

I've already seen this post: [TypeError: message.guild.channels.find(...).then is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61193433/typeerror-message-guild-channels-find-then-is-not-a-function) and am using the code in there, but I'm still getting the error. I'm on Discord.js version 12.2.0, node.js version 12.16.1, and npm version 6.14.4

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I migrate my code to Discord.js v12 from v11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63911361/how-can-i-migrate-my-code-to-discord-js-v12-from-v11)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been updated. Try using:

```
const ticketChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'channelName') 

ticketChannel.send(ticketEmbed)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: When adding .cache.find, it gives me another error:
/Users/scribblenerd/Documents/Discord Bots/Discord.js/raokapp-discord-ticket-bot/node_modules/@discordjs/collection/dist/index.js:158
            fn = fn.bind(thisArg);
                    ^

TypeError: fn.bind is not a function

Comment: (heres an imgur because there isn't any text formatting in comments: https://imgur.com/a/loOCDQK)

Comment: You'll have to do something like
`message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'channelName')` with channelName being the channel's name

Comment: Now its giving me "Cannot read property 'send' of undefined" on  "ticketChannel.send(ticketEmbed)"

Comment: Sorry, check my answer again, gonna update it really quick

Comment: I think it has something to do with the channel being created right before it does that... both `message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'channelName` and `message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === 'channel_Id')` work if I give it an already existing channel...

Comment: Yeah. I'm thinking maybe put a .then(() => {
}) after making the channel and then putting the message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'channelName')

Sorta like an example: (https://pastebin.com/HD5X7LQ3)

Comment: Yep, no problem, glad to help!